# How does one determine how to configure minicom to connect serially to a system on a chip?

Tags: terminal-emulator, serial-console, minicom

I have this [other question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85264/debricking-wnr2000v3-with-raspberry-pi-and-a-serial-connection) in which I am trying to connect to a router using a serial connection from my Raspberry PI.

I am able to see the input from the boot loading messages using minicom but it's a little bit off; the words all appear but they are not left justified.

Also eventually when the router boots up, I get a prompt which gives me a clue as to what SoC is being used on the router, `ar7240>` but when I try to type into the prompt minicom goes crazy and prints like 10 lines for every character I type.

I'm pretty sure I have the basics for baud correct as I pulled those out of the OpenWRT wiki for this specific router.  I'm uncertain if the resister I'm using is the right one; it's definitely a 10k but I'm unsure if the watts are correct.

P.S. I'm pretty new to using minicom for this, but it for some reason reminds me of using Dialup BBS systems with programs like CommIT back in the day.

Comment: Can you show us what your minicom looks like.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'm so new to it that I don't even know what you mean, are you referring to some sort of configuration file, or settings that get written out?

Comment: No I mean to show us a representation, that if you look at it, then it will appear as if you are looking at the minicom.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `screen` to connect to the SoC? I find it much easier to use than minicom. Example use is `screen /dev/ttyS0 9600`

Comment: No I haven't tried that.  I was also thinking of using CuteCom

Comment: I also prefer `minicom`, but this shows that sometimes `screen` or `socat` works when `minicom` has problems: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582714/minicom-cannot-write-to-uart-on-certain-laptop-works-on-different-one